# Vapor Swift How to delete files collected from fileIO

Tags: swift, file-io, vapor, vapor-fluent

I building a server that supports file uploading/deleting using Vapor. I am collecting files to be uploaded using something like this:

```
let path = req.application.directory.workingDirectory
req.fileio.writeFile(.init(data: fileData), at: path)
```

But I was not sure how to delete those files. I only see options to read/stream/collect/write from the [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/files/#write).

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function I use:

```swift
func deleteFile(_ filename: String) throws {
    let filepath = try workingDirectoryURL(with: ["folder/of/files", filename]).path
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filepath)
}
```

Build the path from the project's base folder.

Comment: Where is ```workingDirectoryURL(with:)``` declared? I could not find it.